# how can i make multiple users having different addresses when they register to my contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I want to create a register page where i want users to register and after registration they should get different addresses so that i can fetch their details by address.

Comment: contract Factory {

bytes32[] Names;

address[] newContracts;

 function createContract (bytes32 name)constant returns (address){

    address newContract = new Contract(name);

    newContracts.push(newContract);
 
  return newContract;
 
} 

function getName (uint i) {

    Contract con = Contract(newContracts[i]);
  Names[i] = con.Name();

   
 // bytes memory _ba = bytes(_a);


}

}

contract Contract {


bytes32 public Name;

   function Contract (bytes32 name) {

Name = name;

}
}

Comment: what is wrong with this /